Retrieve events from multiple calendars in Google Sheets
I'm beginner in google script code. I'm stopped by loop in loop trying to get events of multiple google calendar in google sheets. I found some help in this forum (here) but wasn't able to get it working
Here's my last code:
// Menu et bouton pour l'execution du script
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu(' Import Google Agenda')
        .addItem('▶️ Exécuter le script', 'getEvents')
      .addToUi();}

// Script pour récupérer les informations des événements entre deux dates
function getEvents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var start_time = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var end_time = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  
  

  var CALENDER_IDS = [
    "calendar1@group.calendar.google.com",
    "calendar2@group.calendar.google.com",
    "calendar3@group.calendar.google.com",
    "calendar4@group.calendar.google.com",
    "calendar5@group.calendar.google.com",
  ]
// Boucle Pour récupérer les ID de Calendrier
  for (var i = 0, clen = CALENDER_IDS.length; i < clen; i++) {
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CALENDER_IDS[i]);
    //var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(start_time), new Date(end_time));
    var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(start_time), new Date(end_time));
    var calname = cal.getName
    Browser.msgBox(calname);

// Boucle pour récupérer les événenements définies entre les deux dates "start_time" et "end_time"
  for (var j = 0;j<events.length;j++){
    var title =  events[j].getTitle();
    var start_time =  events[j].getStartTime();
    var end_time =  events[j].getEndTime();
    var loc = events[j].getLocation();
    var des =  events[j].getDescription();
    var color =  events[j].getColor();

    // Récupération des insertions des informations des événements (ordre des colonnes du fichier sheets)
    sheet.getRange(j+5,1).setValue(title);
    sheet.getRange(j+5,2).setValue(start_time);
    sheet.getRange(j+5,3).setValue(end_time);
    sheet.getRange(j+5,4).setValue(des);
    sheet.getRange(j+5,5).setValue(color);
    sheet.getRange(j+5,6).setValue(loc);
  }
  }
  Logger.log("Evénements ajoutés dans le fichier.");
}

Any suggestion ? Thanks

Instead of including the whole code, please add a [mcve]. Be specific about what part works. If you get an error, add the textual error message in English. In Google Apps Script, you might temporarily change your account's primary language to English.

Try something like this:
function getEvents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var start_time = sh.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var end_time = sh.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var calidsA = [
    "calendar1@group.calendar.google.com",
    "calendar2@group.calendar.google.com",
    "calendar3@group.calendar.google.com",
    "calendar4@group.calendar.google.com",
    "calendar5@group.calendar.google.com"
  ]
  calidsA.forEach((id) => {
    let cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);
    let evts = cal.getEvents(new Date(start_time), new Date(end_time));
    let calname = cal.getName();
    evts.forEach((ev,j) => {
      let sh = ss.getSheetByName(calname);
      if(!sh) {
        sh = ss.insertSheet(calname);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
      sh.getRange(j+5,1,1,6).setValues([[ev.getTitle(),ev.getStartTime(),ev.getEndTime(),ev.getDescription(),ev.getColor(),ev.getLocation()]])
    })
  });
}


Array.methods()


Thanks for this proposal. But I can't understand "id": no need to declare it?
